# Is there test explorer in intellij idea? (to observe all the tests without execution)? I use TestNG

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, testng, test-runner, test-explorer

In VS and Resharper I could see all test in my solution before any execution, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Windows__Unit_Test_Explorer.html

In Idea I can't find any test explorer, only test runner but it slightly different. Maybe I need to install some dedicated plugins? I use maven and TestNG.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Project view has the special mode for Tests:

[image: tests]

[Check the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-tool-window.html#views) for details.

Comment: That's probably the best IntelliJ can do right now, but still sadly lacking functionality. Something similar to the Visual Studio Test Explorer would be great

Comment: Sadly, if you have integration tests in a different directory than unit tests, that view doesn't pick up on them, even if you mark that directory as test sources root.