# Flutter driver Test Explorer

Tags: flutter, testing, dart, automated-tests, feature-file

is there a way to get some kind of Flutter Test Explorer into the IntelliJ IDE?

I am thinking of something like JUnit has in Visual Studio. Let's say that it should be something like this. My tests are stored in Feature Files.

[image]

If yes please send me a link to an addon or tool.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1:**
I am talking about the tool which "sees" all feature files and scenarios in it before the run. User than can select which scenario will be executed from the list of scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run tests in IntelliJ you should see something very similar to what you have screen shotted above for VS. You may find if you're using a build tool (Gradle/Maven) that running tests defaults to using the build tool to do so but you can switch this back to IntelliJ alone. What are you currently seeing/not seeing in IntelliJ?

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/performing-tests.html for more info + screen shot very similar to VS.

Comment: I am looking for something that can see the Scenarios before the execution.. Lets say that it should see some kind of list of all scenarios before the run. User than can select which scenario should be executed. Idk if you know what I mean

Comment: I understand what you mean. I'm not aware of any such view but will have a (quick) look if anything exists

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44813230/is-there-test-explorer-in-intellij-idea-to-observe-all-the-tests-without-execu If you show Tests only in the project view, then open up the "Structure" tab along side the open class you'll see the methods. It's not the same but it gets you a step closer

Comment: this is sad. The feature you sent does not see feature files :/... I am sure now that the thing I am looking for does not exist yet.

Comment: Seems this feature does exist in JetBrains Resharper but not in IntelliJ IDEA https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/unit_testing.html my guess is its something to do with the way the code can be profiled.

Comment: I checked the plugins for "test explorer" and couldn't find much. Doesn't look like its currently available but happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: How come you would like access to the test explorer anyway? Whats it useful for? In my few years of development I've not needed it

Comment: Let's say you are doing regression testing and you need to do just some of the testing scenarios. Let's say that you have a mess in the scenarios. You have the list of the scenarios which you can execute one by one, or you can select multiple scenarios and execute them together.